# Accessibility with input DateTime type

Tags: accessibility, sapui5

I am attempting to check the accessibility of my web app. To do so, I added the ChromeVox extension to Chrome and turned it on. I see that ChromeVox can read out most of input controls when the user focuses on them. But, with these two `<DateTimeInput>` controls, ChromeVox only reads the place holder values, not the `<label>` for each. It's strange to me.

The following is the code for the `<DateTimeInput>` control portion of my web app:

```
<f:SimpleForm maxContainerCols="3" editable="true" labelSpanL="2" labelSpanM="2" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout">
    <f:content>                  
        <Label text="Start time" required="true" labelFor="startTimeFilter"></Label>
        <DateTimeInput id="startTimeFilter" type="DateTime"  />
        <Label text="End Time" required="true" labelFor="endTimeFilter"></Label>
        <DateTimeInput id="endTimeFilter" type="DateTime"  />
    </f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

The UI looks like:
[image: My web app UI]

How can I change my code to make it such that ChromeVox, and other screen readers, read the `<label>` for each input when the input is focused?

Comment: ah no !! Actually, ChromeVox is only a tool for Accessibility. Accessibility is for the blinds to use the app more easily.

Comment: When user click on any controls, ex input fields, there will be a voice to read out the name, the values of that field or somethings like that, so I think It is not important which tools to use. In my case, everything is ok, but with the DateTime input fields, when user click on it, the voice only read out the placeholder value, not read the label out, therefore user (the blinds), can not understand that field is for which label (Start time or End time, or any things else).

Comment: @Makyen it seems to me that this question is not about using Chromevox but about understanding why doesn't Chromevox read the label for the fields, which is a sapui5 question, perfectly eligible for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Adam, On about my fourth reading, including comments, I believe that is what was intended.

Comment: @ThuanNguyen, I have edited the question to try to make it more clear as to what I now believe you are trying to communicate. If I am not correct in what I have edited this to, please feel free to rollback the edit to the previous version.

Comment: Ah great! your change looks much more clearly! Thank you for your kind effort.

Comment: DateTimeInput is deprecated. See https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DateTimeInput.html Please use the dedicated sap.m.DatePicker, sap.m.TimePicker or sap.m.DateTimePicker controls.